# Change route and pass data to another component

Tags: angular

I want to display multiplication table. I'm using 2 components:

- Homecomponent to take start and end numbers to display table
- xxxComponent to display the table

When I click on the submit button,  I want to display the output in the "Table" route component.

Comment: Could you please add more details to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

html

```
<button type="button" (click)="check()"></button>
```

TS

```
  check(){
    let data = {
      id: id, // custom values here
    };
    this._router.navigate([ 'custom-url' ], { queryParams:data });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from one component to another you can use query parameters.

In home component, when form submitted - navigate to table route and pass query parameters:

```js
onSubmit(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['/table'], { 
    queryParams: { start: '2', end: '9' }
  });
}
```

In xxx component (e.g. table component) read query parameters:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
    // Get parameters
    this.start = params.get('start');
    this.end = params.get('end');
  });
}
```